# Query duplicate user accounts from DB?

Tags: database, customer-account

How can I check for duplicate user accounts using SQL? The back office is not robust enough to show me what I want and I shouldn't really need to get a plugin to do this.

I just want to check to see if there are accounts with the same email address.

Magento 1.4.0.1 (Yes I know it's old but I cannot upgrade due to contractor making core mods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento save customer data at table `customer_entity` in DB and here magento is save `customer email also`.

**customer_entity** table mail table for M`age::getModel('customer/customer') models.`

**If you want to check  mail address already exit in system then try below Query**

> SELECT *, COUNT(*) c FROM customer_entity GROUP BY email HAVING c > 1

Comment: not selecting a single email address. want to find ANY duplicates.

Comment: update..plz now..

Comment: Simpler: `SELECT *, COUNT(*) c FROM customer_entity GROUP BY email HAVING c > 1`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
  count(entity_id) counter,
  email,
  store_id
FROM customer_entity
GROUP BY email, store_id
HAVING counter > 1;
```